# Vue.js props and rest call

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to pass data to my sub-components. The data is provided by an ReST call (using axios).

The problem is that the ReST call is executed after the data function.

Main Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="mainSection">
      <router-view :unit="unit" :config="config"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

var unit = 'test'
var config

axios.get('/unitConfiguration/' + unit)
  .then(function (response) {
    config = response.data
    console.log('rest call done')
  })

var data = {
  unit: unit,
  config: config
}

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  data: function () {
    console.log('get data')
    data.config = config
    return data
  }
}

</script>
```

Sub-component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>test3</span>
    <span>{{ unit }}</span>
    <span>{{ config.room }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Console output is:

```
get data
rest call done
TypeError: t.config is undefined
```

How can I pass the result of the ReST call to subcomponents using props?

Comment: why you dont move your call above the template ?

Answer (score 2):

you can set config as null first, make the http request in `mounted` hook, and set the config value only after a response occurs. You cannot control how long the http request would take, therefore, in your component, you may think about what to display when 'config' is still null.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

var unit = "test";

var data = {
  unit: unit,
  config: null
};

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data: function() {
    console.log("get data");
    return data;
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/unitConfiguration/" + unit).then(response => {
      this.config = response.data;
      console.log("rest call done");
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct about the mounted, it's cleaner that way. However this.config is not defined, I had to set data.config to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your Sub-component you can add :

```
props:{

     unit:{
        type:Object,
        default:function(){
            return{}
        }
    },
    config:{
        type:Object,
        default:function(){
            return{}
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: You are correct, this will set an empty object instead of the null value to be used before the success of the ReST call, thank you.